# Is there a way to share your Facebook Page's stream on a WordPress page or post?

Tags: plugins, facebook

Everybody knows how to share a WP post to Facebook.

**Is the reverse possible**?  Is there a way to share things you post on a Facebook page to a particular WordPress page or post?

If so, I'd really love to hear about a solution; I've googled to no avail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, you need your FB page RSS feed.
To have it you can modify this simple URL:

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=136027779805212&format=rss20

As you can see the number after 'id=' and before '&format' is the page ID.
If you don't know how to find your page ID use this simple online service: http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Then with any Wp feed poster plugin you'll be able to have your FB stream on your blog.

Comment: Thanks Downloadtaky.  I've followed your instructions and have my FB Page's number and have the URL all ready to go.  I tried this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-poster/ ... but I couldn't get that to work.  It wanted me to add a campaign or whatever, but gave me no instructions on how to put the feed on live page or post.

Comment: Any suggestions for a possible plugin or am I searching a wrong way?  I'm searching for "Wordpress Plugin Feed Poster", and the wp-rss-poster is what usually comes up, but that seems kind of antiquated and I don't think it fits my purpose.  Thanks downloadtaky!

Comment: Well, I made a category and put that category on a menu I made, and the fist 15 words show up, and they link to just the same 15 words using wp-rss-poster ... no article or pictures, attachments, links, etc. ... getting there, I think!